# Public beta "trusted user" cannot edit tag wikis

Tags: support, tag-wiki, trusted-user

I recently surpassed 1500 rep in Aviation.SE, earning me the privilege to edit tag wikis.  So I tried it out, and discovered that I actually don't have this privilege:

[image]

Instead after editing, I get the review queue icon, and when I click it, I get an empty queue.

[image]

Why is this not the same functionality that allows me to edit general posts immediately?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Editing tag wikis without approval is a [trusted user privilege](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user), you need 4000 rep on a public beta for this.

Answer (score 6):

You don't have the privilege to edit tag wiki's, you are only able to review them from the suggested edits queue

> [approve tag wiki edits](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits)

furthermore you will not be able to review your own edits because those reviews are not given to you if they pop from the queue (this is true for all reviews)

You'll have to wait till someone else edits a wiki to use your privilege.

Comment: i'm guessing "tag wiki edits are applied immediately" privilege is lumped in with access moderator tools or some other higher privilege?  or does this require consensus regardless?